# stick div position as it is

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a problem with my styling have two divs witch height is auto for both but the thing is when the first div (.filter) height is changed the second div (.posts) goes down as much as height was changed (.filter height +50 , .post down +50px):
[image: how its looks like]

my css :

```
.fp {
position: relative;
    width: 1050px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    left: 170px;
}

.filter {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #1a171a;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.posts {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -280px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #1a171a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

}
```

html :

```
 <div class="fp">
        <div class="filter">

        </div>
        <div class="posts">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left` to `.filter`, erase the negative `margin-top` from `.posts` and add `overflow: hidden` to `.fp` to have the container really covering both elements.

After all the comments, I've set up a complete solution for you here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWNXEN

It adds `margins` where necessary or desireable, defines both elements as `float` (left/right) and lets the container cover the child elements (`overflow: hidden`). Apart from that I removed `position: relative`, which is of no use in this context.

Comment: auto overflow give me scroll down and scroll left how to get rid of them ?

Comment: is kinda working but i got .filter div cut on the butom no chadows and no end after i use hidden

Comment: if i use margin i got everything messed up posts dive goes left top corner and so on

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer `display: inline-block` instead `float`. Floating breaks the normal flow of elements. Also, negative margin isn't a good practice. The declarations `position: relative` or `position: absolute` should be used only on specific cases, not to align all blocks.

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/vg9bajrL/